# Switch only executes if it has one case

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord.js

I´m programming a bot that reply to a certain group of commands. For that, I intended to use a Switch condition, which worked perfectly in my first deploy.

```
bot.on("message", function(message) {
  

  if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
  message.content = message.content.toLowerCase();
  let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");
  
  switch(args[0]){
    
    case "salecs":

      let dt = new Date();
      let hr = dt.getHours();
      let min = dt.getMinutes();
      if (min < 10) {
        hr = hr*10
      }
      let tie = `${hr}${min}`;
      let ti = parseInt(tie);

      if (ti < 1729 && ti > 1529) {
        message.reply('https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almuerzo');
      }else if (ti < 44 || ti > 2259) {
          message.reply('https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cena');
      }else 
        message.channel.send('Salen esos tiritos?  \n@everyone');
    
    break;
  }  
});
```

But when I tried to enter new cases, it stopped working. Not only it doesn't execute the new cases, it neither does the original that used to work.

```
bot.on("message", function(message) {
  

  if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
  message.content = message.content.toLowerCase();
  let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");
  
  switch(args[0]){
    
    case "salecs":

      let dt = new Date();
      let hr = dt.getHours();
      let min = dt.getMinutes();
      if (min < 10) {
        hr = hr*10
      }
      let tie = `${hr}${min}`;
      let ti = parseInt(tie);

      if (ti < 1729 && ti > 1529) {
        message.reply('https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almuerzo');
      }else if (ti < 44 || ti > 2259) {
          message.reply('https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cena');
      }else 
        message.channel.send('Salen esos tiritos?  \n@everyone');
    
    break;

    case "salelol":

      let dt = new Date();
      let hr = dt.getHours();
      let min = dt.getMinutes();
      if (min < 10) {
        hr = hr*10
      }

      let tie = `${hr}${min}`;
      let ti = parseInt(tie);

      if (ti < 1729 && ti > 1529) {
        message.reply('https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almuerzo');
      }else if (ti < 44 || ti > 2259) {
        message.reply('https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cena');
      }else 
        message.channel.send('Salen esos locitos?  \n@everyone');

    break;
    
    default:

      message.reply('No lo tengo ese comando, rey.');

    break;
  }  
});
```

I've been looking for the error but I cannot find where did I got wrong, I hope someone here wll be able spot it and correct me.

Comment: Can you change from switch to if..else if()...else. I think it easier to handle specific case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be because you're declaring variables repeatedly within the same scope. I got an error on your "multiple switch case" example and it said "dt" was already declared. You don't declare variables within cases, you declare them within switch statements themselves.

I recommend declaring dt, hr, min, tie, & ti outside of a case (still within the switch statement) and only doing it once.

Comment: It's also possible to [wrap some brackets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#block-scope_variables_within_switch_statements) around the case statement: `case "foo": { const bar = "baz"; break; }`.

Comment: Thanks! It was that, now I can use as cases as I want!